# Cannot access javascript variable inside symfony controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

On my symfony (v3.4) project, I need to pass some javascript variables from my view to my controller containing a form : I used Jquery and Ajax to send my variable to the right route but for some reason I cannot access it from my controller.

Here is the script part in my twig view:

```js
$(".month").click(function() {

  var click = $(this);

  var month = click.val();
  var year = $("#years").val();

  var url = "{{ path('av_platform_saisie') }}";

  $.ajax(url, {
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'month': month,
      'year': year
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert('OK');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
  });

});
```

And my controller:

```php
public function saisieAction(Request $request)
{

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $thisyear = date("Y");

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // Create the form
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class)
        ->add('ndf', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => NoteDeFraisType::class,
            'label' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ))
        ->getForm();


    // if the form has been submited
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

        if($request->isXMLHttpRequest()){

            $month = $request->get('month');
            $year = $request->get('year');
            $sub_date = $month .'/' .$year;

        }

        $notesDeFrais = $form['ndf']->getData();


        foreach ($notesDeFrais as $ndf) {
            $ndf->setUser($user);
            $ndf->setMonth($sub_date);
            $em->persist($ndf);
        }

        $em->flush();


    }


    return $this->render('AvPlatformBundle:Platform:saisie.html.twig',
        array(
            'year' => $thisyear,  'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

The weird thing is: I tried to send my js variables from a new Twig view that is not rendered by my controller and it's working just fine with exactly the same code so maybe it is a normal behavior ?

**EDIT:** 
I did some debugging and actually and the code inside my `if($request->isXMLHttpRequest())` is not executed

Comment: So you're saying that Twig isn't replacing the {{ path('av_platform_saisie') }} correctly?

Comment: No, the path is correct. I tried the same Ajax request from another view and it works fine

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I can't access it from my controller"

Comment: Basically, I want to get the js variables I sent via Ajax ```php $month = $request->get('month');
                $year = $request->get('year');```

Comment: Did you check the network tab in a browser's dev tools?

Comment: To narrow down the source of your problem, what happens when you dump the `$request` variable from your controller? Also, I note the use of the parameter name `data` in 2 places in your javascript code. May be just fine, but you might try changing one of them.

Comment: @ehymel I get this ```php GET /NotesDeFrais/web/app_dev.php/platform/saisie HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Cookie: PHPSESSID=hfrd6nl5g8fopnk9euijk4lvaq Host: localhost Referer: http://localhost/NotesDeFrais/web/app_dev.php/platform/ Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36 ```

Comment: @ehymel For the script, I changed the name but still the same issue and my Ajax request is sent correctly by the way, so the problem is on my controller

Comment: I think your problem is in the javascript, not the controller. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the right syntax to get your parameters, this is how it should be :

```
if($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
    $month=$request->request->get('month');
    $year=$request->request->get('year');
    $sub_date=$month .'/' .$year;
}
```

And in case you want to get `GET` parametrers, it's this :

```
$request->query->get('get_param');
```

Comment: I already tested the ```php $request->request->get('parameter') ``` syntax but it's not working either. As I said in my original post, the exact same code is working my javascript in on a view that is not rendered by my controller and I can't get why

Comment: I'm importing the right Request class. I'll try to figure out how getContent () method works, thank you for your help

Comment: @AliT what I wrote above is the proper way to get your POST parameters. If it doesn't works, it mean the promblem is elsewhere. Like ehymel said, you should move `url` into ajax options. It's most common. Which Symfony version are you using? It helps a lot to know this. You should edit your question and state which version of Symfony you're using.

Comment: I moved the url into ajax options but nothing new and my Ajax request is correctly sent, I already checked on symfony profiler. I'm using the version 3.4 of symfony, I will edit my original post to precise it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the content of the Request correctly.

Depending on your version of Symfony, other answers might not work and you might have to use:

$request->getContent();

To have access to the associative array containing your data.

(Edit to add my comment): If it does not work, the only other thing on top of my head would be that your IDE autoimport would have imported the wrong "Request" class in your controller ? Make sure you use --> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Comment: or maybe you'll have to use:

$data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);

And then you could access:

$year = $data['year'];

Not sure about having to use json_decode or not to get your associative array ... my Symfony is a bit rusty :D

Comment: I'm using symfony 3 and as I said in my original post, the exact same code is working my javascript in on a view that is not rendered by my controller. But I will explore the $request->getContent() suggestion, thanks

Comment: If it does not work, the only other thing on top of my head would be that your IDE autoimport would have imported the wrong "Request" class in your controller ? Make sure you use --> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Answer (score 0):

Put your url inside the array passed to ajax with, like so:

```
 $(".month").click(function() {
     var click = $(this);
     var month = click.val();
     var year = $("#years").val();

     $.ajax({
         url: "{{ path('av_platform_saisie') }}",
         type: 'POST',
         data: { 'month': month, 
                 'year': year
               },
         success: function (data) {
             alert('OK');
         },
         error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
     });
});
```

Comment: I did it but still the same issue, my ajax request is correctly sent. The problem is not in the javascript

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked the source code of the form, what is the value of `action` attribute? I think you can't add the js `url` for that AJAX request as you did. Ideally, install [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html), and modify as:

```
url: Routing.generate('av_platform_saisie')
```

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the path. Twig path function works fine if you have no parameters to pass. I used FosJsRoutingBundle on other scripts :)